# retrieve a picture stored in a folder Zk Tomcat

Tags: java, zk

I'm new in zk programming, I had stored pictures from my app to a folder out the server(tomcat) and I want to retrieve it , the folder is c:\temps and supposing the picture names is myPic.jpg when I write pics.setSrc("c:\temps\myPic.jpg"); it doesn't work for me what could I do to fix it the storage is very well but retrieving the picture is working only on the Eclipse IDE but in other browsers it's not working

```
@Wire
private org.zkoss.zul.Image pics; 
private static final String SAVE_PATH = "C:\temps\";
private ProfileDao pd = new JpaProfileDao();
private ListModel<profile> profileModel;
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
super.doAfterCompose(comp);
profileModel = new ListModelList<Profile>(pd.findAll());
prfileSelect.setModel(profileModel);
String src="C://tmp//testimg.jpg";
pics.setSrc(src);
Clients.showNotification(pics.getSrc());
}
```

in the browser I have these problem

```
Not allowed to load local resource:file:///C://temps//testimg.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're trying to access to a file in the server side ,the server doesn't know about your disc
so use the aliases for tomcat

```
       <Context crossContext="true" docBase="here_the_path_in_disc" path="project_name/resource_name" reloadable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with ZK for a while, but I'm pretty sure you need to give it an URL, relative to your webapp root directory. So something like "/images/testimg.jpg" or a canonical URL like "https://www.google.dk/images/srpr/logo11w.png", like you would if you ere writing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach will be to use `alternativedocroot` on Glassfish or `aliases` option on Tomcat - [aliases](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation)